# Azure Active Directory B2C Role Template Display name is inconssitent

Tags: powershell, module, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an automation script for creating applications/resources in a ADB2C Tenant. Recently I ran into a troubling issue with the AzureADPreview.

Basically I create an Application, I create it's service principal then I'm assigning roles to this application. One role in particular that is causing me the issues is: User Administrator, or better said User Administrator | User Account Administrator.

What I mean by this? Basically for one tenant, the cmdlet: Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate either returns User Administrator or User Account Administrator which is strange.

Here is the code:

```
# Grant needed Service Principals Permissions
foreach ($displayName in $_.ServicePrincipal.ApplicationRoles) {
    $adDirectoryRole = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq $displayName }
    if ($null -eq $adDirectoryRole) {
        $adDirectoryRoleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq $displayName }
        Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $adDirectoryRoleTemplate.ObjectId | Out-Null
        $adDirectoryRole = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq $displayName }
    }

    Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $adDirectoryRole.ObjectId -RefObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId | Out-Null
}
```

The line `Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $adDirectoryRoleTemplate.ObjectId | Out-Null` throws an error SOMETIMES when the DisplayName is not User Account Administrator.

Please don't tell me the Azure's API code looks like this:

```
if (rand() > 0.5f) { role.DisplayName = 'User Administrator'; }
else { role.DisplayName = 'User Account Administrator'; }
```

What is going on? Why is this the case?
The error thrown

```
Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole : Error occurred while executing ActivateDirectoryRole
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Could not resolve request to a valid role template. A valid value must be specified for 'displayName' or 'roleTemplateId'.
RequestId: 6bc26cc3-ce6d-41d0-abe0-2635d9897b75
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 14:50:19 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - roleTemplateId, PropertyErrorCode  - PropertyRequired
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

PS module: `2.0.2.119 AzureADPreview`

`UPDATE`

Since a lot of the comments are missing the point, I think I need to emphasize the issue.

`Depending` on the tenant when I do the queries mentioned above I get different results. That shouldn't be the case at all, it is a BUG. I don't know where is the bug, in the Azure API, in the PowerShell module, this started some days ago to occur. We didn't change nothing, so I'm blaming the Azure API.

I'm going to attach some photos so you can see clearly the results I'm getting on two different tenants. Please understand that I tested this with 5 or more tenants and this randomness occurs on for each of them.

Some return `User Administrator` and some return `User Account Administrator`. This value doesn't change for that particular tenant after it's deployed. But at the deployment time, that value varies.

Look over these photos:

[image: This is one tenant]

[image: This is another tenant]

These results are obtained from different tenants!!!

Comment: What is `$_.ServicePrincipal.ApplicationRoles`? Can you share more script? You define the `$_.ServicePrincipal.ApplicationRoles` by yourself or it is the data from Azure?

Comment: Logically speaking, you should use `User Account Administrator` here. But I don’t know where your `User Administrator` came from.

Comment: `$_.ServicePrincipal.ApplicationRoles` is defined by me, it's the display name of the role that I want. @AllenWu As I mentioned, in some tenants `User Account Administrator` role doesn't exist, but the `User Administrator` does.

Comment: I created like 4-5 tenants yesterday investigating this issue and it's like a coinflip, I either get `User Account Administrator` or `User Administrator` which is something that's hard to automate :)

Comment: I didn't repro your issue, only get `User Account Administrator`. And it's the `User Account Administrator` in official document as well. Contact Azure support for further confirmation.

Comment: @AllenWu I did, I'm waiting for a response. I will update this post as soon as I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth with Azure Support, we reached the conclusion that this was indeed a bug. They made a blog post about renaming some user roles:

`A 30-day notice announcing the proposed change was posted to the Message center in M365 Admin center in Message ID MC218295 as of July 2020 with information to customers to update their scripts by August 14, 2020.`

The update was finalized in January 20 and today January 29 all my tenants have the same value for the `User Administrator` role.